# Use extension from JavaScript import in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I am trying to use the `dynamo-cache` `npm` module in my `TypeScript` project. Basically, the module adds a new method to `AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient`:

```
AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient.prototype.configCache = function(config) { ... }
```

That way, calling `configCache()` on any `AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient` will enable the cache. However, `TypeScript` doesn't know about this method. I tried to declare an interface like this

```
interface AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient {
    configCache(config: any): void
}
```

but TypeScript refuses to know about `DynamoDB` or dot notation is not allowed in interface declarations. Also, explicitly importing `DocumentClient` causes a conflict when I declare an interface with the same name. How can I make this work?

Answer (score 0):

It might differ based on module system you are using, but declare global is probably what you are looking for:
[Declaration Merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#global-augmentation)

```
declare global {
    namespace AWS.DynamoDB
    {
        interface DocumentClient {
            configCache(config: any): void
        }
    }
}
```

You might have to omit AWS.DynamoDB, can't really validate the code atm.

Comment: The only thing that gave a partial success so far was this: declare module "aws-sdk/lib/dynamodb/document_client" {
    interface DocumentClient {
        configCache(config?: any): void
    }
} - but now I get "TypeError: Cannot read property 'getItem' of undefined
      at Object.get (node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/dynamodb/document_client.js:265:32)"